# How can I make keyboardType = "web-search" or "url" on React Native for Android?

Tags: react-native, url, enums, keyboard, web-search

I have my React-Native app run on Android device.

In the TextInput, I can change the keyboardType to cross-platform values like "numeric" and "email-address", etc. Now I need the keyboardType to be "**web-search**" or "**url**" but it doesn't  make any changes on Android.

I follow this link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#keyboardtype

which has this part:

> enum('default', 'email-address', 'numeric', 'phone-pad', 'ascii- 
>   capable', 'numbers-and-punctuation', 'url', 'number-pad', 'name-phone-
>   pad', 'decimal-pad', 'twitter', 'web-search', 'visible-password')

I don't really understand how to implement this **enum** for **keyboardType** in React Native on Android.

Comment: The documentation says the web-search and url is only for iOS.

Comment: Yes, it said the features only for iOS, but I wonder if there is a way to make it in Android also.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is still not implemented. See the visual guide [here](https://lefkowitz.me/visual-guide-to-react-native-textinput-keyboardtype-options/).

You can however vote for it via https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/support-keyboardtypeurl-on-android